# Not able to validate XSD for an XML with a namespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I am not able to validate the XML using the below XSD,

```
<myTest>
  <standardHeader xmlns="http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader/">
    <data>
      <LEVELDATA>D2D</LEVELDATA>
    </data>
  </standardHeader>
</myTest>
```

XSD Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="myTest">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="standardHeader"   minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="data" minOccurs="0">
                                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="LEVELDATA" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I am getting the below error while validating this XSD with XML,

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'standardHeader'. One of '{standardHeader}' is expected.

How can I provide this `standardHeader` tag:

```
targetNamespace="http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wrong 'namespace' in the XML... (line 2)
When you remove it (or correct it) - it's correct.

**Online-Validator**
https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

**Sample XML-Generator** (from XSD)
http://xsd2xml.com/

**Namespace-Doc**
https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Thanks, But the namespace is required and it is required to support on XSD.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this problem is splitting the XSD into two files:
One for the first absent namespace (`a.xsd`) and one for the second namespace (`b.xsd`) which is declared by `targetNamespace=...` in `b.xsd`  while `a.xsd` does not need that declaration. The second file with its own namespace is imported with the `<xsd:import namespace="..."` instruction. This namespace has also to be included in a namespace declaration of the `xsd:schema` element (here `xmlns:std`).

So `a.xsd` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:std="http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader"
            schemaLocation="b.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="myTest">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="std:standardHeader" minOccurs="0">
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And `b.xsd` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"  
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader">

    <xsd:element name="standardHeader">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="data" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="LEVELDATA" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

These two XSDs do validate your XML file with its namespace as it is.

This answer was inspired by this webpage: ["Multi-Schema Project:
Zero, One, or Many Namespaces?"](http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html). It does not copy the solutions 1-to-1, but is rather inspired by that webpage.

Comment: I tried the above and got this error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'standardHeader'. One of '{"http://tow.gow.ho.com/2009/08/StandardHeader":standardHeader}' is expected.